# How to write the following jQuery a bit better? (fading)

Tags: jquery, css

I'm new to jQuery and I am wondering how I could write the following code better?

```
$( "p:first" ).css({opacity:0.5})
$( "p:first" ).mouseover(function() {
  $( this ).fadeTo( "fast", 1 );
});
$( "p:first" ).mouseout(function() {
  $( this ).fadeTo( "fast", 0.5 );
});
```

Comment: there is nothing much that can be done.. other than caching the selector and may be using `hover()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery [chaining](http://ejohn.org/blog/ultra-chaining-with-jquery/) and also the [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) method wraps the `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` functions in a neat method:

```
$("p:first").css({opacity:0.5})
    .hover(function() {
        $( this ).fadeTo( "fast", 1 );
    }, function() {
        $( this ).fadeTo( "fast", 0.5 );
    });
```

If you need `mouseover`, `mouseout` rather than `enter`/`leave` you can use the `.on` overload:

```
$("p:first").css({opacity:0.5})
    .on({
        mouseover: function() {
            $( this ).fadeTo( "fast", 1 );
        },
        mouseout: function() {
            $( this ).fadeTo( "fast", 0.5 );
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to me the cleanest option :)

Comment: See edited answer as I erroneously said that hover wraps mouseover/out - it doesn't, it wraps enter/leave instead

Answer (score 2):

You should use chaining

```
$("p:first").css({
    'opacity': 0.5
}).on({
  mouseover: function () {
    $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1);
  },
  mouseout: (function () {
    $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.5);
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$( "p:first" ).css({opacity:0.5}).on({
    mouseover:function() {
        $( this ).fadeTo( "fast", 1 );
    },
    mouseout:(function() {
        $( this ).fadeTo( "fast", 0.5 );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$( "p:first" ).css({opacity:0.5})
    .hover(function() {
        $( this ).fadeTo( "fast", 1 );
    },
    function() {
        $( this ).fadeTo( "fast", 0.5 );
    });
```

Comment: RGraham beat me to it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chaining` along with **[.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)** to accomplish your task.

Try,

```
$( "p:first" ).css({'opacity':0.5}).selector.hover(function() {
                                       $( this ).fadeTo( "fast", 1 );
                                   },function() {
                                       $( this ).fadeTo( "fast", 0.5 );
                                    });
```